# Gradle 3 implementation for aar dependency

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-gradle-3.0

I have an `Android` project which has couple of libraries as `aar` dependency. The libraries and the application has the same flavors (*internal* and *external*).
The libraries gets generated as *LibraryName-internal-release.aar* and *LibraryName-internal-debug.aar*, *LibraryName-external-release.aar* and *LibraryName-external-debug.aar*.

In the previous versions of gradle I add the aar file as dependency to the project as follows

```
internalDebugCompile(name: 'LibraryName-internal-debug', ext: 'aar')
internalReleaseCompile(name: 'LibraryName-internal-release', ext: 'aar')
externalDebugCompile(name: 'LibraryName-external-debug', ext: 'aar')
externalReleaseCompile(name: 'LibraryName-external-release', ext: 'aar')
```

How to use the latest `implementation` tag in dependency. I tried using `implementation(':LibraryName@aar')` in gradle 3.0 but it fails to find the correct matching dependency. How to use the `implementation` tag correclty in this situation ?

Comment: dont take much headache just go to the folder of your aar files..then *File -> New - > New Module -> Import .jar/aar files*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `implementation` instead of `compile` simply like this.

```
internalDebugImplementation(name: 'LibraryName-internal-debug', ext: 'aar')
internalReleaseImplementation(name: 'LibraryName-internal-release', ext: 'aar')
externalDebugImplementation(name: 'LibraryName-external-debug', ext: 'aar')
externalReleaseImplementation(name: 'LibraryName-external-release', ext: 'aar')
```